# Passing data parameters between ViewModels using extjs

Tags: extjs

Assuming we have 1 parent viewmodel (corresponding to viewport) and 2 nested (grid and window) viewmodels. On grid actioncolumn click we get a record id, pass it as an ajax request url part and show the response into the window textfields. If no values presented in the response show defaults.

The interesting part is, how to pass the response data to the window textfields using viewmodel binding. I came up with the following solution:

1) On ajax request create a grid viewmodel links using the response data which will be passed through the model, creating defaults if needed:

```
grid.getViewModel().linkTo('custom', {
    reference: 'CustomModel',
    create: data
});

Ext.define('CustomModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'name', defaultValue: 'default name' },
        { name: 'value', defaultValue: 'default value' }
    ]
});
```

2) Using formulas in the grid viewmodel publish data to the parent viewmodel:

```
formulas: {
    publishCustom: function(get) {
        this.set('main.custom', get('custom'));
    }
}
```

3) Populate window textfields with a data from the parent (viewport) viewmodel

```
bind: '{main.custom.name}'
```

You may find the fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/21ae).

This seems a bit not obvious and badly creates an extra data copy. Is there a more cleaner solution for such an issue?

Comment: Why do the grid or the window have a viewmodel at all? It seems as though the request belongs at the level of the parent container, since it has implications for both the grid and the window.

Comment: This is just a simplified example without a bunch of formulas for both nested viewmodels. When there are thousands lines of code in one parent viewmodel it became a bit hard to read and maintain. As far as we use MVC or MVVM pattern it seems proper to have this logic in it's own viewmodel.

Comment: What I'm getting at is that it seems as though the responsibility of doing the load should not be at the level of the of the grid, because that piece of information needs to be communicated across to other components. This behaviour seems like it should be controlled at the container level of whatever controls the window/grid. The way you're doing it at the moment is not a correct use of formulas.

Comment: The only container which controls the behavior of both grid and window is a viewport which has dozens grid/window/whatever bundles with over hundred of formulas and stores which are loaded on an individual treepanel item click. So the Sencha suggestion is to keep all of these staff in a one top level viewmodel?

Comment: I would suggest splitting your architecture into manageable parts. Talking about those pieces in isolation, they seem related and should have some central manager. That central manager doesn't have to be inclusive of everything. If you have a single container with "over hundred of formulas and stores", that might suggest there are problems with splitting of responsibility in your architecture.

Comment: Ok, got it, thank you

Comment: For those who will face the same issue, the revised fiddle is https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/21d2

Answer (score 0):

Much cleaner approach would be to store the commonly accessed objects only in the top level main ViewModel, as all child VM's inherit the data objects in the parent VM's.

You can still bind to them or use in formulas as if they were in the child VM.
See:

[ViewModel Data and Inheritance](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/guides/application_architecture/view_model_internals.html#application_architecture-_-view_model_internals_-_viewmodel_data_and_inheritance)